# Gradle fails to resolve dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

Whenever I add a dependency from an remote repository (jcenter) in Android Studio 1.1 (OS X) I get the following error upon syncing Gradle:

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: <packagename:version>
```

My app's build.gradle is as follows:
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nl.timmevandermeer.cargoapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
     compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
}
```

I have tried changing repositories (jcenter(), mavenCentral(), etc.), reinstalling Android Studio, JDK (7 and 8), changing Gradle version and Android SDK version, none of which worked. Upon running ./gradlew build I get:

```
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.
13:48:04.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
13:48:04.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          :CargoApp:unspecified
13:48:04.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] >
 org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

This is an error I get in other cases as well, for example when trying to use Intellij Idea instead of Android Studio. Running the app without the dependency does work though.

Comment: try removing `.gradle` folder and then run `./gradlew assembleDebug` again

Comment: In Gradle Scripts your project has `build.gradle(Project: Name Project..)` and `build.gradle(Modulo: app) `?

Comment: @hoomi Thanks, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @anderson_acs Yep, my project's build.gradle is as follows:

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    }

Comment: @TimmevanderMeer What is the status of this?

Comment: @JaredBurrows As I mentioned below, I resolved the issue by doing a clean install of my OS. Still not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 27):

A similar problem here, and when I choose Build -> Clean Project
there is a "peer not authenticated" error.

solved by using "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" instead of "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"

```
repositories {
    jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})
}
```

hope this work for you.

Comment: I can't verify, as the problem was resolved by reinstalling my OS. I have tried similar resolutions though, without success.

Comment: It is working fine in my project. so +1. but not in my library module

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem with a library on github, which stated to install it as:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4'
}
```

This workaround seem to work, although it's suboptimal because it doesn't fetch a specific version and leads to Android Studio warnings:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:+'
}
```

Comment: I should emphasize that using the '+' annotation can lead to subtle bugs, as warned by Android Studio. For example, in my experience with the above library, it led to the compiler picking an older version of the lib that didn't support a feature yet that feature was documented on the project's readme. Best to find out from the project owner or otherwise about a specific version appropriate to your situation

Comment: If anyone is having a similar issue with this library, make sure to add the jitpack reference

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was I was declaring jitpack in `buildscript.repositories` instead of `allprojects.repositories` in my package `build.gradle`.

Instead of:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

It should be here:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: settings.gradle

Answer (score 4):

When I added this `com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.5` dependency in my build.gradle (Module Level) file then I got this error.

`Failed to resolve: com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.5`

[image: Error message image]

Then I added `gradlePluginPortal()`
and 'maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }' in **settings.gradle**
groovy

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Add this line
        gradlePluginPortal()
        
        // If issue still persist then try to add this line
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

kts

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        
        // Add these lines if they are not there.
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl ("https://jitpack.io") }
    }
}
```

It worked for me.
[image: Error resolved image]

Answer (score 3):

Rather late but probably your gradle works in offline mode.
Go to File->Settings->Gradle and uncheck the offline mode.
Then try to refresh gradle and it should work

Answer (score 3):

I am behind a corporate firewall.  I had my http settings set, but not my https settings.  So, I added the following to my gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=...
systemProp.https.proxyHost=...
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=...
systemProp.https.proxyUser=...
systemProp.https.proxyPort=...
```

Comment: For me, the password in use was old. My dependencies resolved and downloaded once the password was updated in `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy`

Answer (score 2):

### Top `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
```

### App `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nl.timmevandermeer.cargoapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // <-- use gradle depedencies
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' // <-- brings in v4
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0' // <-- will cause MultiDex exception, you need to choose which ones you want
    // compile 'org.json:json:20141113' // <-- android comes with org.json
}
```

#### Multi-Dex Issue:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'` is too big and should not be used directly. Please choose the modules you want here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: This did not work for me. The problem basically occurred with any project, new or existing, with any library. I reinstalled my OS and the issue was resolved, but the source of the issue remains unknown.

Comment: That just doesn't make sense. There has to be something.

Comment: there is no way to overwrite the org.json that comes with android? it uses 23% more memory than org.json last versions.

Comment: 23% more memory? What?

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem -> ERROR: Failed to resolve:

solved by using `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` instead of 
`maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/'}`

I have added it in project level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in UBUNTU - 14.04 ,

```
>delete .androidstudio1.2 , .gradle , .android  , Android studio project from home directory 
> Launch using studio.sh
>close the dialogue letting you choose new or old setting , just close it using that "x " button 
> then it will set up an virtual nexus 5 
>then there will be two errors saying problem about "sdk" and "gradle "
> Caution : choose the appropriate sdk version by clicking on the link given by where the problem is shown .
> close android studio 
> reopen android studio 
> then you will be thrown a possible  error with jdk not found .
>go to file -> project structure 
> give the path to jdk , in my case its "usr/local/java/jdk..."
>close android studio and open again , the gradle might work well after this .
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added this to my **build.gradle (module:app)**:

```
compile 'com.github.glomadrian:velocimeterlibrary:1.1@aar'
```

However, it gave me an error today. My solution is to use this instead:

```
compile 'com.github.glomadrian:velocimeterlibrary:+'
```