# Gradle build failed for two dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to build gradle with the following dependencies. but its not compiling. I have tried a lot by changing the versions by seeing forums. I search for the dependencies in project structure dialog and found the following two.

```
de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0
com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1
```

Actually I am using two pc. This was build in another pc with following

```
de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1
com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.19
```

Still no luck and the gradle build taking 20-25 minutes each time

Main build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.map"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:0.7.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0'
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like gradle is unable to reach the remote repository. Does your firewall block it, is your internet connection working,...?

Comment: yes internet is working well. how to check firewall is blocking or not?

Comment: the easiest way is to add an explicit exception for it.

Comment: Still no luck. I turned of firewall totally but still its not compiling

Comment: what exactly is the failure message?

Comment: Unable to resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0

Comment: do you use a proxy and if so, have you configured it in gradle? Please add your main build.gradle to the question.

Comment: i don't think you should use two dependency blocks. You can try solutions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077374/gradle-fails-to-resolve-dependencies-in-android-studio. Otherwse I can't help further.